# How to start an independent context managed resource from inside a context managed resource

Tags: python, python-asyncio, with-statement, contextmanager

Let's say I am using messaging protocol A as resource to receive messages on. In these messages is the configuration on how to connect to various device and are received from to time. When a new configuration is received, the script is to connect to the device using messaging protocol B.

Both messaging protocol A and B can sometimes disconnect, therefore I want to use context manager to clean up and reconnect. My problem is that the resources for messaging protocol B are started from within the context manager for protocol A. Thus, when connect is lost for A, all connection for B also get cleaned up. Instead,

```
async def run_resource_A():
  async with resource_A():
    while True:
      configuration = await receive_some_new_configuration()
      asyncio.create_task(run_resource_B(configuration))

async def run_resource_B(configuration):
    with resource_B(configuration):
      # do stuff that shouldnt be killed when resourceA is lost
```

Comment: If you only need A to get the config, why not just get the config, exit A's context manager and then open B's context manager?

Comment: The question isn't clear, without *failover* specifications is not possible to help you.

Comment: I have updated my question, might be more clear when it is async, to explain resource A is waiting on a new configuration to start some resource B. These new configurations can be received from time to time.

Comment: also i made a typo that is now fixed:
"My problem is that the resources for messaging protocol B are started from within the context manager for protocol B" <-- last "protocol B" should be "protocol A"